# Convert YYYY-MM-DD to CYYDDD using groovy

Tags: json, groovy

How do you convert a date in YYYY-MM-DD format to CYYDDD format using Groovy.
For eg 2023-05-17 should return 123137. May 17th is the 137th day of 2023.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a method to LocalDate to support this:

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

LocalDate.metaClass.toCydd = {
    (delegate.year.intdiv(100) - 19) + delegate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyDDD"))
}

String inputDate = "2023-05-17"

String cyyddd = LocalDate.parse(inputDate).toCydd()
assert cyyddd == '123137'
```

Or if you don't want to add it to the metaClass, just use a static method:

```
static String toCydd(LocalDate date) {
    (date.year.intdiv(100) - 19) + date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyDDD"))
}
```